# Can I submit the paper to arxiv and the conference at the same time?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, arxiv

I think the conference where the paper is submitted will have 10 days to start submitting the abstract. There are 23 days before the papers start to be handed in. But my thesis will be completed within a week. The review of the paper takes nearly two months. May I be worried that other people will publish papers with the same idea during the review period.
Can I upload the paper to arxiv now? Then submit it to the conference normally after 20 days?

There is a sentence in the conference request:

> The only exceptions to the above rules are for the authors’ own papers
> in (1) workshops without archived proceedings such as in the ACM/IEEE
> digital library (or where the authors chose not to have their paper
> appear in the archived proceed- ings), or (2) venues such as IEEE CAL
> or arXiv where there is an explicit policy that such publication does
> not preclude longer conference submissions. In all such cases, the
> submit- ted manuscript may ignore the above work to preserve author
> anonymity. This information must, however, be provided on the
> submission form – the program chairs will make this information
> available to reviewers if it becomes necessary to ensure a fair
> review. As always, if you are in doubt, it is best to contact the
> program chairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worrying about other people publishing your paper isn't something you should do. One, it's not in your control, that'll happen if it has to happen. Two, even if it does, there are always other parameters which can differentiate the paper.

This conference says you can post it to Arxiv, so go ahead! But I don't really think it'll stop someone else from publishing their material else where. Especially when the pre-print upload date is so close to the conference many might not even realize that their is a paper with the same domain!

Comment: thank you! But uploading the paper to arxiv can make me feel more at ease, otherwise I will always be frightened. What I want to confirm is: Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: There aren't any "disadvantages" as such. You may even get cited if someone comes across and feels the need to do so. But I don't think it's a practice that is followed commonly. One thing to note is, if its a "blind" submission and your pre-print has names, that might cause some issues!

Comment: Thank you a lot!  But "if its a "blind" submission and your pre-print has names, that might cause some issues!"  I don't quite understand what this sentence means. Can you tell me more specifically?

Comment: Generally top conferences want you to submit the paper without any "names" or "affiliations" on the top. Like an Anonymous submission. If your pre-print has your name then that goes against the conference rule. Glad I could help and all the best :)

Comment: thank you. But I want to make sure: if the conference I submit is as described in the question (don't mind arxiv), then there is no adverse effect. However, some conferences do not have the above statement, and submitting to arxiv will destroy its anonymous review, so it will have a bad impact. Do you mean this?

Comment: It should not have any adverse affect if the conference mentions that you are allowed to put it up on a pre-print server. Yes I mean that exactly!